# Changing exists rule based on choosen option

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

So i have this simple code to input value based on database value in registration form and it's work great,

The code below located at `register.blade.php`

1. This for selecting branch

   ```
   <div class="form-group form-material floating">
     <select class="form-control" name="branch" id="branch">
         <option value="1">Option A</option>
         <option value="2">Option B</option>
     </select>
     <label class="floating-label" for="inputStatus">Branch</label>
   </div>
   ```
2. This one for inputing reference

   ```
   <div class="form-group form-material floating {{ $errors->has('reference') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
           <input type="text" class="form-control empty" id="reference" name="reference">
             <label class="floating-label" for="inputStatus">Reference</label>
             @if ($errors->has('reference'))
                 <span class="help-block">
                     <strong>{{ $errors->first('reference') }}</strong>
                 </span>
             @endif
         </div>
   ```

the code below located at`RegisterController.php`

3. And this one for validation

   ```
   protected function validator(array $data)
    {

    return Validator::make($data, [
   'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
   'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
   'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
   'phone' => 'required|string|min:5|max:20',
   'rate' => 'required',
   'product' => 'required',
   'branch' => 'required',
   'reference' => [
       'required',
           Rule::exists('references')->where(function ($query) {
               if( 'branch' == 1 ){
                   $query->where('references.type', '=', "TOP"); 
               }
               else{
                   $query->where('references.type', '=', "BOTTOM");     
               }
           }),
       ],
      ]
     );
    }
   ```

In registration form when user choose the first option on branch, the user can only write (Example : 'ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI') if the user write another value it will return Error Message : 'Wrong reference code', but when the user choose second option on branch, the user can only write (Example : '123', '456', '789'), , does anyone have and idea how to do it? Thanks

Edit 1 :
The code above works fine, but the exists rule for reference is not working, user still able to input 'ABC', 'DEF', or 'GHI' when choosing second option.

Edit 2 :
I also have this custom validation inside `register.blade.php`

```
fields: {
        reference: {
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'Reference must be filled'
                },
                stringLength: {
                    max: 8,
                    message: 'Max 8 character'
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you need Custom Validation .[Custom Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#custom-validation-rules) . and about query, you can do that inside

```
public function passes($attribute, $value){
  //value will have your reference value
 //Logic here and return true/false
}

 public function message()
    {
       //error message
        //return "The :attribute value doesnt exist.";
    }
```

and if you want to pass parameters in custom rule then you need to use constructor and use it . i.e

```
protected $customParams;
    public function __construct($customParams)
    {
        $this->customParams = $customParams;
    }
```

and rules would look like this

```
 'reference' => ['required',new CustomRule('customvalue')]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is there a way to do that without creating custom validation?

Comment: server side validation .. Check once it passes the validation ,i.e
`
public function store(Request $request)
{
//logic here and return with session::flash(error_msg) and catch session in blade.
}

`

Answer (score 0):

You can make custom validation. So you can move this extra validation inside your custom validation. May be it can solve your problem.

Refer this for more on custom validation: [Laravel custom validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#form-request-validation)

Hope it helps:)

Comment: But how do i change which query that i want to use?, Example (When user choose first option, it will choose query A .. but when user choose option two, it will choose query B)